# Где я допустил ошибку при переборе выпадающего списка?

Tags: javascript, html

Ожидается что при нажатии на выбранный option будет value данного option выводится в console.log

Вот что я написал, но оно не срабатывает:

```js
let select = document.querySelector('.select')
for(let option of select){
    option.onclick = t2 = () => {
        console.log(option.value)
    }
}
```

```css
.select{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 8px 70px;
    border: rgb(20, 102, 134) solid 1px;
    background: rgb(22, 155, 207);
    font-size: 1.3em;
    
}
```

```html
<select class="select">   
           <option >Kryvyi Rih</option>  
           <option >Kyiv</option>   
           <option >Zaporozhe</option>  
           <option >Kropyvnytskyi</option>  
           <option >Odessa</option> 
        </select>
```

Спасибо, большое...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.select');

select.onchange = function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```css
.select {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 8px 70px;
  border: rgb(20, 102, 134) solid 1px;
  background: rgb(22, 155, 207);
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option>Kryvyi Rih</option>
  <option>Kyiv</option>
  <option>Zaporozhe</option>
  <option>Kropyvnytskyi</option>
  <option>Odessa</option>
</select>
```